# C# - how to auto adjust height of a cell of a table in OOXML Word document?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I use OOXML to build a docx invoice in C# and so far all was working well - to print invoice notes I use a collection, which then I process row by row. I had defined a height of the raw as Exact (see my code sample below).

```
 TableRow tblRowHeader = new TableRow();
 TableCell tableCellHeader = new TableCell();
 TableRowProperties rowProperties = new TableRowProperties();
 TableRowHeight tableRowheight = new TableRowHeight();
 tableRowheight.HeightType = HeightRuleValues.Exact;
 tableRowheight.Val = layoutType.Title.TitleHeight;
 rowProperties.Append(tableRowheight);
 tblRowHeader.Append(rowProperties);
```

There was a new request to extend the length of invoice' notes and now I can have a note longer than one line can accomodate, so it is automatically presented on a second line as per attached. As you can see half of it is hidden.

I was trying to address it by setting row's height to auto, but to no avail.

```
tableRowheight.HeightType = HeightRuleValues.Auto;
```

I could find no reference to the height of the cell (I thought I might address it by setting its property to auto), so I need one's advise how to fix it, please?

[image]

Comment: I have also tried `tableRowheight.HeightType = HeightRuleValues.AtLeast;` but didn't work either, so I presume I shall be looking somewhere else.

Comment: The Word WdRowHeightRule enumeration has the following values. wdRowHeightAtLeast=1, wdRowHightExactly=2, wdRowHeightAuto = 0.  So if .HeightRuleValue.Auto isn't 0 this will be the problem  or if casting 0 appropriately doesn't work then your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @Freeflow my understanding was that WdRowHeightRule is Word Interop's and not OOXML one. Yet I will google for OOXML and the rule.

Comment: Because you can then compare the OOXML table row height enumeration with the word table row height enumeration to try and better understand where your issue lies.

Comment: @Freeflow I have created two columns table in WinWord and then opened the Document.xml of my docx, but cannot find something that would address the problem and the text from this example looks absolutely good in two lines.

Comment: `<w:tbl><w:tblPr><w:tblStyle w:val="TableGrid"/><w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/><w:tblLook w:val="04A0" w:firstRow="1" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:noHBand="0" w:noVBand="1"/></w:tblPr><w:tblGrid><w:gridCol w:w="1809"/><w:gridCol w:w="7433"/></w:tblGrid><w:tr w:rsidR="00E95341" w:rsidTr="00E95341"><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="1809" w:type="dxa"/></w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="00E95341" w:rsidRDefault="00E95341"><w:r><w:t></w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc><w:tcPr><w:tcW w:w="7433" w:type="dxa"/>
</w:tcPr><w:p w:rsidR="00E95341" w:rsidRDefault="006E0A24"><w:r w:rsidRPr="006E0A24"><w:t>`

Comment: Could you please use the [edit] link below the question to add the (indent-formatted) XML directly to the question? This kind of thing is very difficult to read in a comment... And this is the Open XML SDK, right? One helpful approach is to create two (very simple) documents: one with and one without the required content. Then use the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool to open the "without" and use the compare feature to compare it to the "with". You should see the different XML and the code to create the one from the other.

Comment: From a quick look I think: Assign *no* `TableRowHeight` to the row and it should automatically be the default (Auto). If it makes you feel better to assign it, then use the `HeightRuleValues` Enum member `Auto`.

Comment: @CindyMeister I will follow your advise to compare both. Thank you.